# Why doesn't our new electric water heater provide hot water at the sink?

Tags: water-heater

The plumber put in a new electric water heater. The water heats up in the tank, but when the water gets to the sink it is cold. The plumber said we most likely have a broken pipe. The cold water keeps filling the hot water tank up and it is leaking out a pipe somewhere.

Why does the new heater not provide hot water to the sink?

Comment: If all faucets, washing machine, etc. are *off*, do you still hear water flowing in/out of the water heater?

Comment: I added an actual question so this post can be on topic, and provided some punctuation and clarification of many of the "it"s in the original post. If I did not grasp your meaning, please edit and clarify what you want to know.

Comment: BTW, did the hot water get to the sink when the old water heater was working? When you turn on the hot water tap at the sink, does any water come out?

Comment: yes never stops and no signs of leaking a hissing sound that never stops water will never stop running.

Comment: Is there hot water in the bathroom: from the tub spout, shower and lavatory?

Comment: Slab and cold water comes out of all faucets when you turn off the water it stops hissing and as soon as you open the valve the hissing comes back.

Comment: It sounds like you need to call in a plumber.  A decent one who will actually work out what's gone wrong, rather than one who installs a heater then runs away without actually testing it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a water leak, then it's likely that the water is leaking away faster than the water heater can heat it.  So when you turn on the tap at the sink, it's cold.

You need to find that leak before it causes serious damage.